# Selenium 2 webdriver and jQuery calendar

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I give input the to a input field which has a jquery ui calendar

```
id("dateSelecterInput").sendKeys(date);
id("dateSelecterSubmit").click();
```

When you enter something in a input field the calendar pops up, as it should, but when then cover the submit button which is below the input field. The problem is that for Webdriver it cant click the submit button, probably since its not visible ?!?

The problem can be solved be clicking a other element, but its a hack, how to solve it proper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use date pickers all over our production site . After clearing the date field and sending keys, can't you press the return key to get the same result , instead of clicking on the button?

if pressing return is not an option, then , yeah, modify your css so that the button is always visible. selenium works the same way an end user would see the site, so.

Comment: Webdriver doesnt have a concept of return. The button is visible in css terms, I was maybe unclear there, but the calendar overlaps it when displayed since the button is right bellow the input field. And then webdriver cant click the button, just as a user cant click the button before a date is selected on the calendar.

Comment: And then webdriver cant click the button, just as a user cant click the button before a date is selected or he manually clicks the "close" images on the upper right corner of the calendar. The issue with webdriver is that I send the date directly to the input field, and since jquery has attacted some event to the field the calendar gets expanded, my submit button get covered and webdriver cant click it.

Comment: Yeah but ,  you can  press return by doing  driver.sendKeys(KEYS.Return) , thus  , finishing the process .  Not doable ?

Comment: thanks crazyaboutliv, the Keys.Return trick solved the problem!